# How to duplicate objects in animation?

Tags: animation, objects

I want to copy some object in animation, like using a particle system.
I mean at frame 10 copy an object, then at frame 20 copy again, and the first object should not disappear.

It is like a particle system, but I would like to control more details.
Like Unity3D's Prefab and Instantiate.duplicate

Comment: Can you place a question with a question mark [?] in your writing above? Please show your work as a Blender screen capture to see memory or cpu compute requirements for you duplicated object. How many objects are being duplicated? 8 ? 888 ? Quantity matters. Please clarify you question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The render visibility of an object or object hierarchy can be animated.  Thus the viewer will perceive the object to appear.  The object can be off camera or in a different layer.
- Python is available to you.
- One or more Particle systems is available and these particle systems can be coordinated by Python
- Particle Instance is available